# C# - Winforms webBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, xbox360

How can i pass the URL property in web browser into an if statement....

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var GameStats = comboBox1.Text;
        if (GameStats == "BattleField: Bad Company 2")
        {
            //Make URL equal to http://statsverse.com/
        }

    }
```

Comment: You're talking about the `WebBrowser` Control right? Or the client's default web browser application (IE/FF/Chrome)?

Comment: No the windows form item "WebBrowser"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WebBrowser.Navigate()`

Answer (score 0):

Try `webBrowser1.Navigate("http://statsverse.com/");`